# Join in PHP query

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

In my user profile:

I want to make a list with the landmarks that user like and it has been added at the favorite table , in my query i join the favorites and landmark table ,but nothing is retrieved ?

// php

```
 <?php
        include "config.php";
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $userid = array_key_exists('userid', $_GET) ? $_GET['userid'] : null;
        $landmarkid = array_key_exists('landmarkid', $_GET) ? $_GET['landmarkid'] : null;

        $data=array();

        $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT c.userid,c.L_ID,u.Title,u.Image,u.L_ID FROM favorite  c inner join landmarks  u 
        on u.L_ID=c.L_ID WHERE ".(isset($userid) ? "c.userid=$userid" : (isset($landmarkid) ? "c.L_ID=$landmarkid" : "") )." ORDER BY c.L_ID");

        if($q){
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($q);
            if($num_rows > 0){
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
                    $data[]=$row;
                }
            }
            echo '{"favourites":'. json_encode($data) .'}'; 
        }
    ?>

    //Tables 

        CREATE TABLE `favourite` (
          `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `L_ID` int(11) NOT NULL
        ) 

        CREATE TABLE `landmarks` (
          `L_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `Image` text NOT NULL,
          `Title` text NOT NULL,
        )


        CREATE TABLE `users` (
          `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're volunteers here. It takes time to read lots of code. Unfortunately your question contains an enormous amount of irrelevant code, but does not contain either sample data from your tables or a sample of the result you want. Please [edit] the question to show some samples.

Comment: what do you exactly want? to join 2 table into one?

Comment: i have edit the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like that?

```
SELECT l.* FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN favourite AS f ON f.userid = u.userid
INNER JOIN landmarks AS l ON l.L_ID = f.L_ID
WHERE u.userid = YOURUSERID
```